# How to inject script on a Webpage?

Tags: html, google-chrome, scripting

I have many websites that has the following script tag in the head section:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.doSomething(someObject);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         .....
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to inject a script before any page loads so that these websites will have the access to the function `doSomething` which is defined my custom script. How do I make sure that my custom script is executed before any of the scripts in the HTML file?

I don't want to modify the front-end code. I thought of using extensions but they run after all the scripts on the page. Is there a way I can do this?

Even a Chrome specific way would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

[Declaratively injected scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively) in Chrome extensions [can be configured](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) to run at document start:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.nytimes.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately that's not the whole story, because injected scripts run in an isolated environment, so you can't modify the `window` object of the page itself. You can, however, modify the DOM (which is still empty at this point) to add a `<script>` element that loads a script from your extension, as described in Method 1 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/14637). That second script will then run in the context of the page itself, and can do whatever it likes.